# ASP.net to AngularJS date format

Tags: javascript, asp.net, angularjs, date

I have an ASP.net application that uses AngularJS for the display of data.
I'm retrieving a list of data that contains a date column. When I use console.log to print the data that is being returned from the server/database, I am seeing the date printed in the format "Thu Feb 11 2016 00:00:00 GMT+1100 (AUS Eastern Daylight Time)".
Why is the server returning a date in this format? How can I go and change the date format? I'd like the format to be DD/MM/YYYY HH:MM
Here is some of my code that retrieves the data:

```
public JsonResult GetEventList()
{
var result =    from e in db.events
                select new
                {
                                 event_id = e.event_id,
                                 event_name = e.event_name,
                                 event_date = e.event_date
                 }
return Json(result.ToList(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Json response looks like:

```
{ event_id: 1, event_name: 'Event', event_date: 'Mon Jan 11 2016 00:00:00 GMT+1100 (AUS Eastern Daylight Time)' }
```

Comment: How are you returning date information from ASP.NET to the client?

Comment: "I have an ASP.NET that" ... an ASP.NET *what*?

Comment: GetEventList() returns a json. Can you show the json response in your question?

Comment: Your json response is not double quoted.

{
    "event_id": 1,
    "event_name": "Event",
    "event_date": "MonJan11201600: 00: 00GMT+1100(AUSEasternDaylightTime)"
}

Comment: What data type is event_date in your model class events?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you're getting:

`Mon Jan 11 2016 00:00:00 GMT+1100 (AUS Eastern Daylight Time)`

You can try adding a custom format to the Date object, something like this:

```
Date.prototype.formatMMDDYYYYHHMMSS = function () {
    return (this.getDate()) +
        "/" + ((this.getMonth() + 1) < 10 ? ("0" + (this.getMonth() + 1)) : (this.getMonth() + 1)) +
        "/" + this.getFullYear() +
        " " + this.getHours() +
        ":" + this.getMinutes() +
        ":" + this.getSeconds();
};
```

**How to use this function:**

Set a date variable with the long date string.

```
var date = "Mon Jan 11 2016 00:00:00 GMT+1100 (AUS Eastern Daylight Time)";
```

Convert the date into the `Date()`.

```
date = new Date(date);
```

Then, by using `date.formatMMDDYYYYHHMMSS()`, you get the converted date.

<kbd>[Demo with Javascript](http://jsfiddle.net/dannyjhonston/L1wv9f25/)</kbd>

```js
var date = "Mon Jan 11 2016 00:00:00 GMT+1100 (AUS Eastern Daylight Time)";

Date.prototype.formatMMDDYYYYHHMM = function() {
  return (this.getDate()) +
    "/" + ((this.getMonth() + 1) < 10 ? ("0" + (this.getMonth() + 1)) : (this.getMonth() + 1)) +
    "/" + this.getFullYear() +
    " " + this.getHours() +
    ":" + this.getMinutes();
};

var datea = new Date(date);
console.log(datea.formatMMDDYYYYHHMM());
```

**Using a $filter in AngularJS:**

```js
(function() {
  "use strict";
  var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

  app.controller("Controller", ["$scope", "$filter",
    function($scope, $filter) {

      $scope.eventList = [{
        "event_id": 1,
        "event_name": "Event",
        "event_date": "Mon Jan 11 2016 00:00:00 GMT+1100 (AUS Eastern Daylight Time)"
      }, {
        "event_id": 2,
        "event_name": "Event 2",
        "event_date": "Mon Jan 11 2016 15:48:00 GMT+1100 (AUS Eastern Daylight Time)"
      }];

      // Using the toDateTime $filter in the Controller.
      $scope.showDate = function(event) {
        console.log($filter("toDateTime")(event.event_date));
      };
    }
  ]);

  app.filter("toDateTime", function() {
    return function(x) {

      Date.prototype.formatMMDDYYYYHHMM = function() {
        return (this.getDate()) +
          "/" + ((this.getMonth() + 1) < 10 ? ("0" + (this.getMonth() + 1)) : (this.getMonth() + 1)) +
          "/" + this.getFullYear() +
          " " + this.getHours() +
          ":" + this.getMinutes();
      }

      return new Date(x).formatMMDDYYYYHHMM();
    };
  });
})();
```

```html
<html data-ng-app="myApp">

<head>
  <title>Demo AngularJS</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body data-ng-controller="Controller">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>
          event_id
        </th>
        <th>
          event_name
        </th>
        <th>
          event_date
        </th>
        <th>
          Show Date
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr data-ng-repeat="event in eventList">
        <td>{{event.event_id}}</td>
        <td>{{event.event_name}}</td>
        <td>{{event.event_date | toDateTime}}</td>
        <!-- Using the toDateTime $filter in the View. -->
        <td>
          <button data-ng-click="showDate(event)" type="button">Show Date</button>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your time from ASP side is in DateTime format,

Retrieved From ASP at the controller :
"/Date(1441164289937)/"

To filter (at controller side):

```
.filter('convertDateTime', function($filter) {

    return function(input) {

        var timeFormat = 'dd MMM yyyy HH:mm'; //date format 

        if(input == null) { return "";}

        return $filter('date')(parseInt(input.substr(6)), timeFormat);

    };

})
```

U can amend the following javascript code above to ur liking. But the logic is the same. But you would need to change ur DateTime to a javascript Date first. There are many examples out there. Hope that helps.